# how to build Hadoop eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I would like to be able to build Hadoop eclipse plugins from

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/

I have managed to get the source into my Eclipse workstation using subclipse, and now I want to build the jar.  Do I build it as executable jar?  There is no launch configuration associated to the source.  Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is :

> 1. Checkout the code from Apache's SVN (Done in your case).
> 2. Modify build.properties in /src/contrib/eclipse-plugin and add : eclipse.home=/path/to/your/eclipse/folder
> 3. Download apache forrest 0.8 and sun jdk (Preferably java 6).
> 4. Run ant command as "ant clean package -Djava6.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun (Change the path according your machine and make sure you are connected to the network)
> 5. At this point eclipse plugin should be there in /build/contrib/eclipse-plugin but the jar is not yet ready to work as
>      it misses some required jars.
> 6. Add the following jars from your HADOOP_HOME/lib folder to the plugin/lib folder commons-configuration-1.6.jar
>      commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar
>      jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar
> 7. Modify MANIFEST.MF in /META-INF of the jar to include the path of these added jars.
> 8. Copy this jar to plugins folder of eclipse
> 9. Run "eclipse -clean"

There are some posts over the net for the same. See if they work for you :

[Link 1](http://yiyujia.blogspot.in/2012/11/build-hadoop-eclipse-plugin-from-source.html)

[Link 2](http://www.danielbit.com/blog/opensource-software/compile-hadoop-eclipse-plugin-1-1-2-jar-on-64-bits-ubuntu-12-04-with-eclipse-indigo)